# error C3861: 'findEssentialMat': identifier not found - Opencv 2.4.9 with visual c++ 2010

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, visual-odometry

in my code I have the following includes:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
```

and the code:

```
//recovering the pose and the essential matrix
Mat E, R, t, mask;
E = findEssentialMat(points2, points1, focal, pp, RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, mask);
recoverPose(E, points2, points1, R, t, focal, pp, mask);
```

But with Opencv 2.4.9 with visual c++ 2010 I obtained the compile errors:

```
error C3861: 'findEssentialMat': identifier not found
error C3861: 'recoverPose': identifier not found
```

How to solve them?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you obliged to use such an old version of OpenCV or could you upgrade to a newer version? I would recommend that :). With a quick google search I could not even find the source code or a documentation of 2.4.9.
Edit: Seems like the functions are [not available](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html) in 2.4.9

Comment: Umm I think there is no solution. I have to migrate to OpenCV 3.0.0 version :-( Another thing is that it also seems no vc10 directory in the OpenCV 3.0.0 version, so maybe I also need VC++ 2012...

Comment: Another option: it is possible to have findEssentialMat and recoverPose to insert directly in the code and compile them?